# For loop with function (from r package) issue

Tags: r, scope

I'm trying to make many plots with the 'DoHeatmap' function in the Seurat package. I wrote a loop that should insert the new parameter on each iteration, but I'm running into scoping errors, from what I understand. Here is simple reproducible example...

```
library(Seurat)

data("pbmc_small")

a<-rep("pbmc_small",3)

for (i in 1:length(a)) {
DoHeatmap(object = a[i])
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `subset(wk,subset = CellType==df[i,1])`? I'm not sure that this is the issue, but you should not use `subset` there. Its documentation contains a warning about scoping. Try `wk[wk$CellType == df[i, 1],]`. If you need further help, provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: PS: Why do you use a `data.frame` when a vector `cell <- c("Mac","T","Neutrophil","Mast","Eo","B","Proliferating")` would be sufficient?

Comment: What R version you are on? I am not able to install `Seurat` package on `3.6.1`.

Comment: The subset command is not the issue, if I remove it and iterate any other parameter the same issue occurs. Whatever variables I put within the call to DoHeatmap will not be evaluated. You're right, a vector would be sufficient, but in reality I have additional parameters that I wanted to control with each iteration, however I removed all but one for this post to keep things simple. I've altered the post to be simple and reproducible, thanks for any help. I'm using R version 3.6.0

Comment: That package is nasty. It wants to install something called "Miniconda", which I simply can't do (and don't want to).

Comment: Anyway, I don't think `a[i]` is a "Seurat object", which is what `DoHeatmap` expects.

Comment: Yep. I am facing the same installation issue. It wants me to install package called `multtest`, when trying to install that it says `package ‘multtest’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)`

Comment: I wouldn't call the package nasty, it's been cited in a lot of peer reviewed literature and is used regularly to analyze transcriptional data. 'multtest' is available on bioconductor. The basis of my question is how to solve the scoping issue, if a[i] is evaluated in the right environment then it would refer to a Seurat object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this wasn't a scoping issue after all, @Roland's comment put me on the right track. Here is an option that works well enough...

```
data("pbmc_small")

a<-rep("pbmc_small",3)

a<-list(pbmc_small,pbmc_small)
b<-c("groups","letter.idents","RNA_snn_res.0.8")

List<-list()
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  for (ii in 1:length(b)) {
    print(i);print(ii)
    plot=DoHeatmap(object = a[[i]],group.by=b[ii])
    List[[length(List)+1]]<-plot 
  }
}
```